# The best navigation code to using rigidbody in unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, position, move, physics

I want to press the key once

My cube moves to the right and rotates 90 degrees

The rotation is well done

But it does not move well

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed;

    public float time;

    public GameObject contactPoint;

    private Rigidbody rig;

    private void Start()
    {
        rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            StartCoroutine(RotatePlayer(Vector3.forward * 90, Vector3.right, time));
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            StartCoroutine(RotatePlayer(Vector3.back * 90, Vector3.left, time));
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator RotatePlayer(Vector3 byAngle, Vector3 dir, float inTime)
    {

        Quaternion fromAngle = contactPoint.transform.rotation;
        Quaternion toAngle = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles - byAngle);

        for (float t = 0; t < 1; t += Time.deltaTime / inTime)
        {   
            rig.MovePosition(transform.position + (dir * speed * Time.deltaTime));
            rig.MoveRotation(Quaternion.Slerp(fromAngle, toAngle, t));

            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: first you are spamming the coroutine call when you press D like as long as d is down you start like 1000 coroutines, you should check that you do not have a coroutine already running. also when using physics use FixedUpdate so you apply forces every fixed amount of time

Comment: @Skin_phil actually OP is using `GetKeyDown` which will start a new routine exactly **once** per button click ;) correct about `FixedUpdate` though, OP should rather use `yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();` **before** using `rig.MoveXY`

Comment: Please define `does not move well` .. what is the expected behavior and what happens instead?

Comment: @derHugo yes you're right! My bad, but i still think that his main problem is the stuttering that might be caused by not using fixed update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is: You should do Physics related things like movement of a `Rigidbody` only in [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html).

For Coroutines Unity provides [`WaitForFixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForFixedUpdate.html) which does exactly what the name says, making sure the code after it is executed in a `FixedUpdate` physics call.

```c#
private IEnumerator RotatePlayer(Vector3 byAngle, Vector3 dir, float inTime)
{
    yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();

    // here I would also use "rig" instead of "transform"
    Quaternion fromAngle = contactPoint.transform.rotation;
    Quaternion toAngle = Quaternion.Euler(rig.eulerAngles - byAngle);

    for (float t = 0; t < 1; t += Time.deltaTime / inTime)
    {   
        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();

        // here I would also use "rig" instead of "transform"
        rig.MovePosition(rig.position + (dir * speed * Time.deltaTime));
        rig.MoveRotation(Quaternion.Slerp(fromAngle, toAngle, t));
    }
}
```

beyond that it is a bit unclear what exactly you define as `not move well`. You also should somehow make sure that only one routine is running at a time. Either by terminating already running routines like

```c#
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
        StartCoroutine(RotatePlayer(Vector3.forward * 90, Vector3.right, time));
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
        StartCoroutine(RotatePlayer(Vector3.back * 90, Vector3.left, time));
    }
}
```

or preventing new routines from starting until the current one is finished using a flag like

```c#
private bool alreadyRotating;

private IEnumerator RotatePlayer(Vector3 byAngle, Vector3 dir, float inTime)
{
    if(alreadyRotating) yield break;

    alreadyRotating = true;

    ......

    alreadyRotating = false;
}
```